# break or return from when expressions

Tags: kotlin

What I would like to do:

```
when(transaction.state) {
    Transaction.Type.EXPIRED,
    //about 10 more types
    Transaction.Type.BLOCKED -> {
        if (transaction.type == Transaction.Type.BLOCKED && transaction.closeAnyway) {
            close(transaction)
            break //close if type is blocked and has 'closeAnyway' flag
        }
        //common logic
    }
    //other types
}
```

I cannot write `break`:

> 'break' and 'continue' are not allowed in 'when' statements. Consider using labels to continue/break from the outer loop.

Is it a way to `return/break` from `when` statements? Or what is the best way to solve it?

Comment: how about just putting the "common logic" stuff in an `else` block?

Comment: @OliverDain, good idea! But is it replacement for all cases where `break` may need?

Comment: I think I agree that break functionality would be nice (though you could always do the if/else thing). Just suggesting a workaround until such time as the Kotlin team decided to implement (or not).

Comment: Did you try doing what it suggested and adding labels to break to?

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom, yes, I did. It is not allowed to label `when`.

Comment: I think you need a better example - this one is begging for an `else` as @OliverDain suggested. I don't mind `break` in loops, but using it (or `return` with no value) to get out of  a when expression seems ugly.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) with a [return at label](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels):

```
when(transaction.state) {
    Transaction.Type.EXPIRED,
    //about 10 more types
    Transaction.Type.BLOCKED -> run {
        if (transaction.type == Transaction.Type.BLOCKED && transaction.closeAnyway) {
            close(transaction)
            return@run //close if type is blocked and has 'closeAnyway' flag
        }
        //common logic
    }
    //other types
}
```

Comment: that's odd @IgorGanapolsky, you may need ask a question on SO if you still have the issue when trying to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

it should work, here is a Kotlin Playground link to demonstrate `run` + `return@run`: https://pl.kotl.in/yBP4E8ycc

Answer (score 16):

You can use labels to break/continue/return. e.g.:

```
transactions@ for (transaction in transactions) {
    when (transaction.state) {
        Transaction.Type.EXPIRED,
        Transaction.Type.BLOCKED -> {
            break@transactions
        }
    }
}
```

See [Returns and Jumps - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html) for more details.

Comment: Good workaround, but I cannot accept it as the answer because it may be some code after `when`.

Comment: @Feeco. Thank you. I think I slightly misunderstood your question. I'll post another answer.

Answer (score 4):

Work around using `apply()`:

```
transaction.apply {
    when(state) {
        Transaction.Type.EXPIRED,
        //about 10 more types
        Transaction.Type.BLOCKED -> {
            if (type == Transaction.Type.BLOCKED && closeAnyway) {
                close(this)
                return@apply
            }
            //common logic
        }
        //other types
    }
}
```